# HTML anchor: href vs. onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am using a jQuery slideshow plugin (fiftyfirst/slideshow).

There is a gallery and two navigation buttons to click through the images. This usually works perfectly fine.

However on some Windows computers the navigation buttons fail to work in Firefox and Chrome. IE always works and on Mac computers it generally also works with all browsers.

In the faulty cases the images do not slide, but instead the browser jumps to the top of the page.

I found the following code e.g. for the prev button:

```
<a data-track-action="carousel_prev" data-track-event="click" data-slide="prev" data-bind="previous-slide" href="#">‹</a>
```

I assume there is also an onclick event attached to this element, but did not find it in the code, yet.

I suspect that the issue is related to the execution order of href and onclick. In the faultless cases onclick is executed, in the faulty cases href is triggered first.

May this speculation be correct or am I on the wrong track? In either case: What could I do here?

Comment: check for debug console errors.

Comment: you could try contacting the plugin author https://github.com/fiftyfirst/slideshow

Comment: Is `href="#"` needed at all if the click event is handled by javascript / jQuery?

Comment: This is what the author included, however it is necessary for correctness of html and the behavior of the anchor element.

Comment: The click event handler no doubt prevents the default action of the `<a>` element (following it to its href attribute's value), so you need to figure out why those click event handlers aren't always being bound. As charlieftl said, check for errors in the console/dev tools (hit F12) of the browser when it fails to load, and see what errors are being shown there.